# matrix search through java 2D ArrayList of Strings for duplicate instances, breadth first?

Tags: java, arrays, search, matrix, arraylist

I have a corpus of data, a matrix, a 2D ArrayList of String, [3][indeterminate, quite many], of the form:

```
deduct under |||the council \'s demerit points system |||further # points |||
lead |||him |||the council \'s demerit points system |||
want |||their licenses |||they |||
lie between |||# and # |||the general index |||
exceed |||# |||the general index |||
lie between |||# and # |||the roadside index |||
advise to avoid |||prolonged stay |||respiratory illnesses |||
be necessary to stay in |||these areas |||it |||
exceed |||# |||the roadside index |||
be necessary to stay in |||these areas |||it |||
hoist |||attention tv/radio announcers |||october # , # red flag |||
be item of |||interest |||the following |||
hoist at |||silverstrand beach |||the red flag |||
issue on |||behalf of the provisional regional council |||the following |||
publish by |||the provisional regional council |||the tang dynasty |||
present under |||# sections |||the artefacts |||
```

*The delimiter **"**|||**"** is not actually part of the data, I just put it here to facilitate readability.

It's part of a java program, generated from an input file by this code:

```
List<List<String>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'(?![a-zA-Z])"); 
//while the file is still reading
while ((line_0 = br_0.readLine()) != null) 
{
    List<String> three = new ArrayList<>();         
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line_0);
    int j = 0;
    while (m.find()) 
    {
        three.add( m.group(1) );
    }
    arr.add( three );
}
```

For each datum I want to search through the array, possibly in a breadth first way, and if that datum reappears elsewhere in the matrix I want to make not of the place this occurs, and of course the catalyst that generated this find, the searchee if you will. How to do this efficiently? I'm working with a lot of data.

Comment: All three strings are equal?

Comment: no the three strings usually are not equal

Comment: Sorry, I meant "to be treated equally" w.r.t. their overall comparison.

Comment: ah, yeah i guess so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence: for storing triples verb(object,subject):

```
public class Sentence {
private String verb;
private String object;
private String subject;
public Sentence(String verb, String object, String subject ){
    this.verb = verb;
    this.object = object;
    this.subject = subject;
}
public String getVerb(){ return verb; }
public String getObject(){ return object; }
public String getSubject(){ return subject; }
public String toString(){
    return verb + "(" + object + ", " + subject + ")";
}
}
```

Collecting and linking Sentences:

```
public class Ontology {
private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
/*
 * The following maps store the relation of a string occurring
 * as a subject or object, respectively, to the list of Sentence
 * ordinals where they occur.
 */
private Map<String,List<Integer>> subject2index = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String,List<Integer>> object2index = new HashMap<>();
/*
 * This set contains strings that occur as both,
 * subject and object. This is useful for determining strings
 * acting as an in-between connecting two relations. 
 */
private Set<String> joints = new HashSet<>();
public void addSentence( Sentence s ){
    // add Sentence to the list of all Sentences
    sentences.add( s );
    // add the Subject of the Sentence to the map mapping strings
    // occurring as a subject to the ordinal of this Sentence
    List<Integer> subind = subject2index.get( s.getSubject() );
    if( subind == null ){
       subind = new ArrayList<>();
        subject2index.put( s.getSubject(), subind );
    }
    subind.add( sentences.size() - 1 );
    // add the Object of the Sentence to the map mapping strings
    // occurring as an object to the ordinal of this Sentence
    List<Integer> objind = object2index.get( s.getObject() );
    if( objind == null ){
        objind = new ArrayList<>();
        object2index.put( s.getObject(), objind );
    }
    objind.add( sentences.size() - 1 );
    // determine whether we've found a "joining" string
    if( subject2index.containsKey( s.getObject() ) ){
        joints.add( s.getObject() );
    }
    if( object2index.containsKey( s.getSubject() ) ){
        joints.add( s.getSubject() );
    }
}
public Collection<String> getJoints(){
    return joints;
}
public List<Integer> getSubjectIndices( String subject ){
    return subject2index.get( subject );
}
public List<Integer> getObjectIndices( String object ){
    return object2index.get( object );
}
public Sentence getSentence( int index ){
    return sentences.get( index );
}
}
```

A small test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Ontology ontology = new Ontology();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'\\('(.*?)','(.*?)'\\)"); 
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if( m.matches() ) {
            String verb    = m.group(1);
            String object  = m.group(2);
            String subject = m.group(3);
            ontology.addSentence( new Sentence( verb, object, subject ) );
        }
    }

    for( String joint: ontology.getJoints() ){
        for( Integer subind: ontology.getSubjectIndices( joint ) ){
            Sentence xaS = ontology.getSentence( subind );
            for( Integer obind: ontology.getObjectIndices( joint ) ){
                Sentence yOb = ontology.getSentence( obind );
                Sentence s = new Sentence( xaS.getVerb(),
                                           xaS.getObject(),
                                           yOb.getSubject() );
                System.out.println( s );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
'prevents'('scurvy','vitamin C')
'contains'('vitamin C','orange')
'contains'('vitamin C','sauerkraut')
'isa'('fruit','orange')
'improves'('health','fruit')
```

Output:

```
prevents(scurvy, orange)
prevents(scurvy, sauerkraut)
improves(health, orange)
```

Comment: would you mind to sort of, help me understand what's going on with those hash maps, i've never used that before

Comment: Adding some comments: I hope that this is sufficient. - You should find plenty of tutorials on map usage in Java on the web.

Answer (score 0):

**Obsolete** - Removed the text of the old answer. Keeping it because of the comments below.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out something like A(B,C) and X(B,Z) then A(B,Z) you know? so I want to find if I can match the string anywhere else as a prerequisite for that next step, I guess I should search all three columns once for each entry so if [0][0] is 'A' then look to see if A is mentioned anywhere else, and find out where, you know?

Comment: So, first look in column 1 for doubles, then in 2, 3 and so on? But a (clearer) example of the "next step" might help to get it right first time.

Comment: i want to learn rules by inference, so for instance contains(vitamin c, oranges), prevents(scurvy, vitamin c) will finally yield prevents(scurvy, oranges)

Comment: so i guess of most importance would only be columns 2 and 3 since the antecedents are whats in column 1

Comment: This would be a cinch with a rule based system :-)

Comment: what do you mean by that? like prolog? i tried it with prolog but it gets all mucked up by duplicate words

Comment: Something similar, yes. - In any case, the symbols (your strings) must be correct in the sense that "scurvy" is always written as "scurvy", and "scurvy" must alway mean "scurvy", i.e., the  deficiency disease.

Comment: actually i was thinking it would be better to be able to generalize them to some kind of higher order representation with something like wordnet, but... i'm been having trouble trying to figure that one out.

Comment: From the orange-scurvy example I can deduct that from x(a,b) and y(b,c) you want to deduct x(a,c). Thus, a reference from b in y (at 2nd pos) to x, where it occurs in 3rd pos, would help. Correct?

Comment: If you have the triples as facts in a RBS, you can write all kinds of rules, not just simple inference deductions. - See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29

Comment: I have experimented: linking each subject to triple indices, each object to triple indices and keeping track of symbols that appear a both lets you create all first order inferences.

Comment: I'm in Singapore so I'm going to sleep now, I'm going to work on this tomorrow, I'll keep you posted on the progress.

Comment: Posted what I have, another answer.